# Share photo TO Phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, share

I am trying to send to my phonegap application an image from the image gallery, using the 'share' feature.

1. To display my app in the 'share' list, I have followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908224/share-something-to-a-phonegap-app)
2. I have added the following in my AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
       </intent-filter>
   ```
3. My app is now properly listed in the 'share' list
4. I click on my app
5. I am using [cordova-webintent](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent) plugin to intercept the intent and get EXTRA( my image )
6. I am using this code below to get my image

   ```
   window.plugins.webintent.getExtra(window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_STREAM, 
        function(data) {
            console.log(data)
           }, function(e) {
               console.log(e)
               // There was no extra supplied.
           }
   );
   ```
7. The success callback is called, but 'data' contains '**true**'

I was expecting to have either an url, or a base64 string of my image

FYI, i have also tried window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_TEXT but i guess this is only for sharing link, text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We are also looking for same solution for Android and IOS. I tried to understand the Java code. I think it will work only for Maps, because the the code written regarding maps. Please let us know if there are any solutions.

thank you,
Narendra

Comment: Hi Narendra, I have adjusted the code to make it work. Please check  the forked repository: https://github.com/florentvaldelievre/virtualartifacts-webintent
The plugin is for Android