# Share Image from Gallery to MyApp using Framework7.js in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, webintents, html-framework-7

Stuck with a this thing, I am using Framework7.js at present. Please help me, any other alternative will also be appreciated. Android is the platform I am operating on

Comment: maybe duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908224/share-something-to-a-phonegap-app

Comment: Thanks amir, but i have followed this one. I am unable to find out the right place for 2nd snippet of code i.e. the file where it should be.

Comment: so why you didnt say? we cant guess what you tried :) he pointed to some plugin did you install this plugin? if yes just add his code after device ready event, than do whatever you want with the image. please edit your post and edit all the details

Answer (score 1):

You need only to setup a custom URL scheme (thanks Eddy Verbruggen for [this helpful plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme)  ) and you'll be able to reach the app from Gallery sharing button.

Be careful of following the caveat on plugin readme and choosing a scheme not in common use ( *yourAppName://* may be the best one to avoid confusion for users ).