# Can't fetch URL or data using webintents

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, webintents

I am trying to use webintents with a cordova app to be able to send images from another app to mine.

I am using cordova 5.1.1 and added the following plugins to my android platform project:

```
com.virtualartifacts.webintent 1.0.0 "WebIntent"
cordova-plugin-camera 1.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.0 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 2.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.1.0 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
```

The index.html file for the project looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebIntent Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/webintent.js"></script>
    <script>
        function init() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready",deviceReady,false);
        }
        function deviceReady() {
            console.log("App started. Device ready");
            window.plugins.webintent.getExtra(window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    function(data) {
                        console.log(data); // which never gets called
                    }, function(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                        // I simply get the message "Error"
                    });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <h1>Demo WebIntent</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

so nothing really special here.
after searching the net for a while I found some information about the webintent plugin being buggy (as mentioned [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908224/share-something-to-a-phonegap-app). So i found the patched version and double checked that the right code is in the WebIntent.java file, which is.

I also added the intent-filter tags in the AndroidManifest.xml file like so:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

When i installed the app on the device and try to share an Image my app shows up in the list of apps that are able to handle this sharing, and i also get the "App started..." text, so I know it gets called.

But no matter what kind of image i try i always reach the "error" part of the getExtra method and my console.log only shows "Error". Debugging is done directly on the device via GapDebug.

Is there anything I am missing or has anyone an idea on making my app getting images from other apps to work with?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in that Cordova plugin, use this fork instead

https://github.com/florentvaldelievre/virtualartifacts-webintent

so just remove the old one

cordova plugin rm com.virtualartifacts.webintent

and add the new one

cordova plugin add https://github.com/florentvaldelievre/virtualartifacts-webIntent.git

that should be it, although I'm didn't need to run js\webintent.js to get it to work.

This works when selecting a single image, arrays of streams doesn't seem to work yet.

Comment: thanks a lot for that information. Too bad that multiple images/files don't seem to work, since that is also something i need...