# How to receive shared data in Meteor cordova mobile app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, meteor

I have a meteor chat application and now want to add capability of receiving data shared from other apps, on both IOS and Android

I found few solutions to do so in cordova (ateleast in android) 
[receive-data-with-app-built-by-phonegap-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338637)
[share-something-to-a-phonegap-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908224)
However couldn't add those plugins in meteor builds.

Anyone has done this before?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the MongoUrl to your other app. That will connect your meteor app to other app.

I hope that can solve your problem.